# TSQL use joined table data as function parameters

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql

Can anybody briefly explain why it is not possible to use values of the table as parameters for the joined function?

```
;CREATE FUNCTION "foo" ( @id INT )
RETURNS @result TABLE
(
    "value" INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @result SELECT @id * 2
    RETURN
END;

;WITH "cte" AS
(
    SELECT "id" = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
)
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    cte
    , "foo"(cte."id")
```

The last line throws an error ( ~ cte."id" can not be bound ).
It doesn't matter if it's a cte or table.

Comment: Reason is, your function returning a `TABLE` and you are trying to add a table to a column. As @DimiToulakis mentioned, you can use `CROSS APPLY` or `OUTER APPLY` here. Or change your function to a single valued function.

Comment: @DimiToulakis Thanks. Although it's only three words, I'd like to accept your hint as correct answer. Could you add it as answer?

Comment: @Nico Added as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining result sets coming out from table valued function is done by using `CROSS APPLY`.